# Setting autofocus on a textarea with reagent

Tags: clojurescript, autofocus, reagent

How do I set the autofocus attribute on an element with reagent, so that the produced HTML looks like below?

```
<textarea autofocus></textarea>
```

The effect of course being that the text area will have the focus of the browser once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found a way to produce the sought after HTML, but the same effect seems to be achieved through JS by adding the `:auto-focus` option to your element:

```
[:textarea {:auto-focus true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else searching this topic, I'll add that my own issues with `:auto-focus` turned out to be due to my password manager plugin. The accepted answer works just fine with the plugin turned off.